# redirect all subdomains from http to https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect all subdomains of `example.com` from `http` to `https` using `.htaccess`?

I've searched Google and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

To redirect all subdomains of `example.com` to `https` , you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```