# integrating .htaccess code to redirect all subdomains from http to https into Wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350226/667903), I gained `.htaccess` rules for rewriting subdomains from `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

However, adding them to my .htaccess has not successfully redirected my Wordpress MU subdomain sites from `http://*.example.com.au` to `https://*.example.com.au`.

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
### Caching ###

# WPSuperCache
...
# END WPSuperCache

### URL Rewriting ###

# example.com.au > www.example.com.au #

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>

# http://*.example.com.au > https://*.example.com.au

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example.\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>

# General redirects and rewrites

Redirect 301 ...

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...nothing related to example.com.au or *.example.com.au
</IfModule>

### Wordfence ###

# BEGIN litespeed noabort
<IfModule rewrite_module>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
</IfModule>
# END litespeed noabort

### Wordpress ###

# Begin Wordpress
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress

### MainWP ###
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: example.\.` has an additional `DOT` after example but it might be typo

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you @anubhava. Working now.

Comment: Add an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Comment: Or maybe I should delete the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has an extra DOT after `example` which will expect to match a single character afterwards here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example.\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Fix it by using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.example.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```