# Redirect all subdomains to another domain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all *.example.org.au to *.somethingelse.org.au (including www.).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350226/667903), I've tried the following in example.org.au's .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.org\.au$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.somethingelse.org.au%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>
```

But www.example.org.au doesn't redirect at all.

Help appreciated.

Comment: remove `(?!www\.)`m that explicitly excludes www;  https://regex101.com/r/FUMI4T/1

Comment: Thanks Dusan, add an answer and I'll accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `(?!www\.)` from your RewriteCond, that explicitly excludes `www.`

More info: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

> Negative lookahead:
>      `(?!regex)`
>   Similar to positive lookahead, except
>   that negative lookahead only succeeds if the regex inside the
>   lookahead fails to match. `t(?!s)` matches the first t in `streets`.